# JQuery permission denied in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, plugins, onload, permission-denied

I am getting "permission denied error in jquery jquery-1.12.4.min.js" on continuously loading of page. Once this error occurred, every Jquery object  throws permission denied error.

I am using IE9. Initial 2 3 load do not throw exception.

[Error Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqrRw.png)

i have attached error Trace as an image.

once this error is thrown for eg: method ShowOptViewToggleBar() throws same error. Also every method which follows this

Comment: Are you loading jquery from your server or from a CDN?

Comment: from the server, file is added to the solution

Comment: Check your server log to see why it's denying this.

Comment: TraceHigh:2018-06-14 05:59:50:0546Z:BrowserLogEvent.ScriptError:MsgId=e1fea6ed-7563-46dc-824a-d29933ee61d3:TranId=e1fea6ed-7563-46dc-824a-d29933ee61d3:ProcessIdentifier=10.25.39.21-3440-2018-06-14 05:18:26:4433Z
    InternalProperty.SequenceNumber=15870
    CoreProperty.ThreadID=5
    CoreProperty.Guid=e486cc7f-9c4b-4796-a72e-e3f4bd7fd65c
    DisplayName=News
    InstanceName=201@920000000095_48063
    ErrorLine=2
    ErrorCharacter=12114
    ErrorMessage=Permission denied
    ErrorCode=0
    Url=http://mywebsite/News.Web/NewsMonitorXWeb/UX/20.0.629.2/JavaScript/jquery-1.12.4.min.js

Comment: Put it in the question so it's readable.

Comment: Check the permissions on the `jquery-1.12.4.min.js` file.

Comment: i copied error trace,
 ErrorCharacter=12114 ErrorMessage=Permission denied
 ErrorCode=0 
Url=http://mywebsite/News.Web/NewsMonitorXWeb/UX/20.0.629.2/JavaScript/jquery-1.12.4.min.js

permission on the files are read,write,modify

Comment: Where did you copy the error trace? I don't see it in the question. Maybe there's something in .htaccess that's causing this.

Comment: TraceHigh:2018-06-14 05:59:50:0546Z:BrowserLogEvent.ScriptError:MsgId=e1fea6ed-7563-46dc-824a-d29933ee61d3:TranId=e1fea6ed-7563-46dc-824a-d29933ee61d3:ProcessIdentifier=10.25.39.21-3440-2018-06-14 05:18:26:4433Z 

InternalProperty.SequenceNumber=15870 
CoreProperty.ThreadID=5
 CoreProperty.Guid=e486cc7f-9c4b-4796-a72e-e3f4bd7fd65c DisplayName=News 
InstanceName=201@920000000095_48063

Comment: ErrorLine=2 
ErrorCharacter=12114 

ErrorMessage=Permission denied 

ErrorCode=0

Comment: I SAID TO ADD IT TO THE QUESTION, NOT A COMMENT